# Error con pip y virtual enviorement

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

Trabajando en un entorno virtual, no me permite instalar nada con pip, ya que me sale el siguiente eror:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya intente reinstalar python y Visual Code y no me deja, al igual que ya actualice mis variables de entorno.
Alguien que me pueda echar la mano, se lo agradecería mucho, ya me desespere:(

Comment: prueba con la invocación manual `python -m pip install flask`. Si no funciona prueba también a crearte un usuario nuevo que no tenga espacios en el nombre y prueba desde ahí. A veces los espacios en las rutas de archivo en windows suelen dar dolores de cabeza.

Comment: Si estás usando una instalación de python que no has hecho tú, es mejor asegurarse que esté bien actualizado: `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`. Si no te deja, es que tienes algo que te está impidiendo su uso (eg: un firewall o un antivurus)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¿Cómo esta tu carpeta de usuario?
En como mencionas que el comando pip te funciona de manera normal, pero no en el venv, puede ser que tenga conflictos con tu usuario, ya que si este tiene espacios en el nombre causa fallos en el entorno virutal.
Intenta crear otro usuario como administrador o cambiar de nombre a tu carpeta de user (Si es que el nombre esta separado con algún espacio)

Comment: Gracias, era el problema con mi carpeta user, cree un nuevo user y quedo ☺